# How to delete Custom card from cardview

Tags: android

I am using a custom card view for showing the server data. I have a bunch of cards which appear one by one. So, I want to know that how should I delete the entire card on click of the delete button.
Scanner Image

[image]

here is the adapter code :

```
    public class CardAdapter<M> extends BaseCardAdapter implements View.OnLongClickListener {
            private List<Model> modelList;
            private Context context;
            TextView tvCount;

            public CardAdapter(List<Model> modelList, Context context, TextView tvCount) {
                this.modelList = modelList;
                this.context = context;
                this.tvCount = tvCount;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return modelList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCardLayoutId() {
                return R.layout.card_item;
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onBindData(final int position, final View cardview) {
        //      if (modelList==null || modelList.size()==0){
        //          return;
        //      }
        //        tvCount.setText((position)+"/"+modelList.size());

                // ImageView imageView=(ImageView)cardview.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView textView = (TextView) cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                TextView textView1 = (TextView) cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                TextView textView4 = (TextView) cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                TextView textView5 = (TextView) cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                TextView textView6 = (TextView) cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                TextView textView7 = (TextView) cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView7);

                final Model model = modelList.get(position);
                //textView.setText ("Name" + ": " +  model.getName());
                String name = "<font color=#FFFFFF>Name:</font>";
                String nameOne = "<font color=#FFFFFF>" + " " + model.getName() + " </font>";
                textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(name + nameOne));

                //textView1.setText("Job Title" + ": " +  model.getJobTitle());
                String job = "<font color=#FFFFFF>Job Title:</font>";
                String jobOne = "<font color=#FFFFFF>" + " " + model.getJobTitle() + " </font>";
                textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(job + jobOne));

                //textView2.setText("Company" + ": " +  model.getCompany());
                String company = "<font color=#FFFFFF>Company:</font>";
                String companyOne = "<font color=#FFFFFF>" + " " + model.getCompany() + " </font>";
                textView2.setText(Html.fromHtml(company + companyOne));

                //textView3.setText("Telephone" + ": " +  model.getTelephone());
                String telephone = "<font color=#FFFFFF>Telephone:</font>";
                String telephoneOne = "<font color=#FFFFFF>" + " " + model.getTelephone() + " </font>";
                textView3.setText(Html.fromHtml(telephone + telephoneOne));

                //textView4.setText("Mobile" + ": " +  model.getMobile());
                String mobile = "<font color=#FFFFFF>Mobile:</font>";
                String mobileOne = "<font color=#FFFFFF>" + " " + model.getMobile() + " </font>";
                textView4.setText(Html.fromHtml(mobile + mobileOne));

                //textView5.setText("Email" + ": " +  model.getEmail());
                String email = "<font color=#FFFFFF>Email:</font>";
                String emailOne = "<font color=#FFFFFF>" + " " + model.getEmail() + " </font>";
                textView5.setText(Html.fromHtml(email + emailOne));

                //textView6.setText("Address" + ": " +  model.getAddress());
                String address = "<font color=#FFFFFF>Address:</font>";
                String addressOne = "<font color=#FFFFFF>" + " " + model.getAddress() + " </font>";
                textView6.setText(Html.fromHtml(address + addressOne));

                //textView7.setText("Narration" + ": " +  model.getNarration());
                String narration = "<font color=#FFFFFF>Narration:</font>";
                String narrationOne = "<font color=#FFFFFF>" + " " + model.getNarration() + " </font>";
                textView7.setText(Html.fromHtml(narration + narrationOne));

cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Model model = modelList.get(position);

                customDialogAddContactnShare(model);

                return false;
            }
        });

        cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView2).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Model model = modelList.get(position);

                customDialogSearch(model.getCompany());

                return false;
            }
        });

        cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView4).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Model model = modelList.get(position);

                customeDilogMobCallnMsg(model.getMobile());

                return false;
            }
        });

        cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView3).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Model model = modelList.get(position);

                customDilogTeleCallnMsg(model.getTelephone());
                return false;
            }
        });

        cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView5).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Model model = modelList.get(position);

                customDialogMail(model.getEmail());

                return false;
            }
        });

        cardview.findViewById(R.id.textView6).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Model model = modelList.get(position);

                customDialogMapAddress(model.getAddress());

                return false;
            }
        });

        //tvCount.setText(modelList.size());
        //Toast.makeText(context," " + modelList.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Picasso.with(context).load(model.getImage()).into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return false;
    }
```

like so. 
Here, I want to delete the first position card (The card whichever comes up after the swipe). If the user clicks on delete button the 1st card gets deleted.

Help me with this.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: is that a recyclerview?

Comment: no. I am just using a custom card view with an adaptor.

Comment: share your adapter and activity class code

Comment: does the adapter have a list?

Comment: ok wait. will share the code

Comment: on delete button clicked remove the item from the list and notify the adapter that it changed, to achieve that you need to keep tracking of the current shown position

Comment: can you show me with code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

For this You can first find position in your adapter, and call method for delete card at that position,as like below,get data from database

```
private void deletePlace(int position) {
        DBOpenHelper dbOpenHcelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
        dbOpenHelper.deleteData(arrayList.get(position).getEVENT());
        arrayList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position,arrayList.size());
```

}

I hope  may this will help you!!

Comment: I am not using database